# Extracting attributes list with unique values from QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, unique-value, value-list

How can be extracted and exported a list of all single values without duplicates from the column of an attribute table (e.g. `"formations"` column values of an attribute table of a vector geologic layer in order to have the list of formations without duplicates)?

Comment: Exported to where? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following tool will output a file containing all unique values in a column.

***Vector > Analysis Tools > List unique values***.

1. Select the input layer
2. Click the ellipsis within *Target field(s)*. In the window that pops up, select your column of interest.
3. Optional: Select *Skip output*
4. Click *Run*

[image]

Voila! The output file containing the unique values is created.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates from any column, you can use the "Delete duplicates by attribute" tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Open the Processing Toolbox panel:

[image: Open the Processing Toolbox panel.]

Run the "Delete duplicates by attribute" tool:

[image: Run the "Delete duplicates by attribute" tool:]

As a result, you will get a layer where the column you selected does not contain duplicates. The column of the resulting layer can be exported to different formats, such as an ODS table.

Right click on the result layer:
[image]

Select column export options:
[image]

Comment: This approach will also preserve the geometry, which is barely required